# Overloading Python math functions using Cython

Tags: python, cython

Here is my basic problem:

I have a Python file with an import of

```
from math import sin,cos,sqrt
```

I need this file to still be 100% CPython compatible to allow my developers to write 100% CPython code and employ the great tools developed for Python.

Now enter Cython.  In my Python file, the trig functions get called millions of times (fundamental to the code, can't change this).  Is there any way that through some Python-fu in the main python file, or Cython magic otherwise I can instead use the C/C++ math functions using some variation on the Cython code

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double sin(double)
```

That would give me near-C performance, which would be awesome.

[Stefan's talk](http://www.behnel.de/cython200910/talk.html) says specifically this can't be done, but the talk is two years old, and there are many creative people out there

Comment: I'm pretty sure cpython already uses these functions internally. Why would they reimplement basic mathematical operations?

Comment: If you're going to call the trig functions for large numbers of values, consider packing those values in Numpy arrays and calling `np.sin` and friends.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Having looked at the .c code that Cython generated from my file that imported the sqrt function, it doesn't use the math.h versions, which is unfortunate

Answer (score 4):

In an [example](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html) from Cython's documentation, they use a cimport from a C library to achieve this:

```
from libc.math cimport sin
```

Comment: But this import doesn't overwrite the import from the python library in pure python mode

Comment: Why don't you query the user for a command line argument or function parameter that indicates to your code whether you're running in python or Cython, and then accordingly import the appropriate `sin` function?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Cython expert, but AFAIK, all you could do is write a Cython wrapper around `sin` and call that. I can't imagine that's really going to be faster than `math.sin`, though, since it's still using Python calling semantics -- the overhead is in all the Python stuff to call the function, not the actual trig calculations, which are done in C when using CPython too.

Have you considered using [Cython pure mode](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html), which makes the source CPython-compatible?

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to do it in pure Python mode.  It seems, and I think I can verify this, that Cython does do the magic under the hood to use the `math.h` functions.

Comment: EDIT: Cython does not use the c/c++ math functions, even when variables are statically typed.

Comment: @ibell: it does when you import them explicitly: `from libc.math cimport sqrt`.

Comment: @larsman : That only is possible if you are using a Cython .pyx file.  Here I have a pure Python file, so doing the import in the .py file is impossible.  If I could have a switch to do something like

if cython.compiled:
    cython.import('from libc.math cimport sqrt')
else:
    from math import sqrt

it would still be valid CPython code, but would swap sqrt functions (NB: the code I show here doesn't actually work, but it is my idea of how it COULD work)

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question eight years later, this is what worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10 using the system CPython vesion 3.7.5 and Cython3 version 0.29.10 from the Ubuntu repostory.

The Cython documents on [Pure Python Mode](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html) give an example that works. It looks a bit different to the examples in the old answers here so I guess the document has been updated since.

The Python file needs a *conditional* import, which works fine using normal CPython:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# from: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html
# mymodule.py

import cython

# override with Python import if not in compiled code
if not cython.compiled:
    from math import sin

# calls sin() from math.h when compiled with Cython and math.sin() in Python
print(sin(0.5))
```

The Cython language constructs must be put in a file with the same name but a ".pxd" suffix:

```
#cython: language_level=3
# from: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html
# mymodule.pxd

# declare a C function as "cpdef" to export it to the module
cdef extern from "math.h":
    cpdef double sin(double x)
```

I used the "--embed" option to create C-code for a stand-alone Linux ELF executable to test this. The GCC compiler line needs "-lm" to import the maths module that contains sin.

```
cython3 --embed mymodule.py

gcc -o mymodule mymodule.c -I/usr/include/python3.7 -lpython3.7m -lm
```

Comment: The trick here seems to be that the `cpdef` creates something that's replaced with a C function where possible, but has a Python wrapping. The Python wrapping is important because it means that `from math import sin` _can_ assign to `sin` (since it's just overwriting the wrapping). It's nice trick to get round the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your problem, but the [Cython documentation on interfacing with external C code](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications) seems to suggest the following syntax:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double c_sin "sin" (double)
```

which gives the function the name `sin` in the C code (so that it correctly links to the function from `math.h`), and `c_sin` in the Python module.  I'm not really sure I understand what this achieves in this case, though - why would you want to use `math.sin` in Cython code?  Do you have some statically typed variables, and some dynamically typed ones?

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I am missing something, it won't quite do the trick.  I tried adding it to my PXD file on a whim, but it didn't quite seem to work.  Thanks for your help though.